# Why "angular is running in the development mode" printed multiple times?

Tags: angular, identityserver4

The "angular is running in the development mode" should only be displayed when an app is launched, however, in my app (Angular7) I see that message being displayed multiple times at different intervals. 
Has anyone run into such an issue?
[image: Chrome console log]

Comment: Do you have any online example?

Comment: Please share an example of screenshot of your log. Also, please check if you have an empty `<a>` tag anywhere. It will reload the application on click.

Comment: @ChunbinLi unfortunately this is all running locally and it will be difficult to recreate online.

Comment: @ashish.gd added the console log

Comment: Because the app starts (so the message is logged), then it redirects to demo.identityserver.io, which then redirects to your app again, which thus restarts and prints the message again. Don't you see the lines starting by "Navigated to" in your log?

Comment: @JBNizet, I did see the lines and I totally ignored them :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've got this behaviour on my browser console too.
In my case it was triggered by dynamically bootstrapping and injecting Angular components into a native DOM element on demand (interaction with 3rd party libraries, we all love it right?).

In my situation this message was triggered by this line of code:

```
this.applicationRef.bootstrap(Component, DOMElement);
```

Where this.applicationRef is an instance of the component constructor:

```
import {ApplicationRef} from '@angular/core';
... some non relevant code
constructor(private applicationRef: ApplicationRef)
... some non relevant code
```